# Cannot completely understand the meaning of different trace flags for nodes configuration

Tags: networking, wireless, ns2

I am new to NS and trying to understand the code of AODV routing protocol.
But I'm unable to understand what macTrace, AgentTrace, movementTrace, routerTrace mean when configuring the nodes.

Here is the small snippet :

```
$ns node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
             -llType $val(ll) \
             -macType $val(mac) \
             -ifqType $val(ifq) \
             -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
             -antType $val(ant) \
             -propType $val(prop) \
             -phyType $val(netif) \
             -channelType $val(chan) \
             -topoInstance $topo \
             -agentTrace OFF \
             -routerTrace OFF \
             -macTrace ON \
             -movementTrace ON
```

Comment: ns2 doc https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/index.html .... AODV ex : AODV-examples-01.18.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uOvyXih1W2PDPP-2LYOJw4lYzSTRWPAd/view?usp=sharing .... All ~3000 ex https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Comment: ns2 trace files https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+trace+files → → http://nsnam.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/NS-2_Trace_Formats ... ...  "tracefile-doc.tar.gz" : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeS1weGNuVWwwLWc/view?usp=sharing